# cannot display the button using jquery

Tags: jquery

Just want to display the button "Show more" but it throws error "button is not defined".Could you check what is wrong with my code.

```
var para= $('<div>');               

$.each(data.results, function(i, res) {                    

                    info = $('<p>'),
                    button = $('<input type="button" id="load_more" value="Show More" />');

                    info.html(res.text);                    
                    para.append(block);                   

                });

$("#load").html(para);
$("#load_posts").html(button);
```

Comment: It is about "Variable scope": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't stuck in loop, if you don't have to change value or anything for `button`.

```
var para= $('<div>');  
var button = $('<input type="button" id="load_more" value="Show More" />');     

$.each(data.results, function(i, res) {                    

                info = $('<p>');
                //button = $('<input type="button" id="load_more" value="Show More" />');

                info.html(res.text);                    
                para.append(block);                   

});

$("#load").html(para);
$("#load_posts").html(button);
```

Comment: Oh. There is a mistake. The `,` after `info = $('<p>')`. That should throw another error. It is in the original already. Hmm, trying to replicate in console...